# prepareForSegue crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So my segue is crashing here and I am not sure why...There are no errors shown but when I run the app in the simulator and then hit the button to segue it crashes with this error in the debugger: Could not cast value of type 'DNApp.StoriesTableViewController' (0x1077d5a80) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x109d8ca18).
(lldb)

Below is the relevant code:

```
class StoriesTableViewController: UITableViewController, StoryTableViewCellDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoryCell") as! StoryTableViewCell

    let story = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureWithStory(story)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell   
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("WebSegue", sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

// MARK: StoryTableViewCellDelegate

func storyTableViewCellDidTouchUpvote(cell: StoryTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
    // TODO: Implement Upvote
}

func storyTableViewCellDidTouchComment(cell: StoryTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentsSegue", sender: self)
}

//MARK: Misc
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentsSegue" {
        let toView = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentsTableViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        toView.story = data[indexPath.row]
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The book says to set sender to cell in the delegate function `func storyTableViewCellDidTouchComment(cell: StoryTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentsSegue", sender: cell)
}` I have the problem that I don't know why prepareForSegue is called twice, once with the cell as the sender, and the second time with the button as sender. Which resulted in the same error, but checking the sender with if let helped, to fix it at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your cell is not a `UITableViewCell` but a `StoryTableViewCell`. If you use `if let` instead instead the forced wrapping you are seeing your app will not crash, however you won't be able to access the values in the cell, you just need to cast your cell correctly as below:

```
class StoriesTableViewController: UITableViewController, StoryTableViewCellDelegate {

var myIndexPat = NSIndexPath()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    myIndexPath = indexPath
    performSegueWithIdentifier("WebSegue", sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentsSegue" {
        let toView = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentsTableViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(myIndexPath) as! StoryTableViewCell
        toView.story = data[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I get what you are referencing, but it seems to still give me an error replacing it with UIStoryTableViewCell...the error is saying this: Could not cast value of type 'DNApp.StoriesTableViewController' (0x10b6e6a80) to 'DNApp.StoryTableViewCell' (0x10b6e5ff0).
(lldb)      it says it is an undeclared type...??

Comment: @user3708224 sorry I just spot the problem, you need to use a index in the indexPathForCell, that you can retrieve from didSelectRowAtIndexPath  and cast the result of that to UIStoryTableViewCell. I fix the answer you just need to add a variable myIndex and populate in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I hope that help

Comment: ok, could you provide the code example for clarity...( I am a bit of a rookie as you can tell...) thanks!

Comment: Still saying UIStoryTableViewCell is undeclared type...?...but thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry it is not UIStoryTableViewCell, but just StoryTableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misread your question entirely!  Your crash is still due to force unwrapping.  You should use optional bindings (`if let`) instead.  You can do multiple bindings at once and use a `where` clause to make the code a little cleaner, too:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let toView = segue.destinationViewController as? CommentsTableViewController where segue.identifier == "CommentsSegue" {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell( cell ) {
            toView.story = data[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func storyTableViewCellDidTouchComment(cell: StoryTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentsSegue", sender: self)
}
```

In prepareForSegue method sender is kind of StoriesTableViewController class,force cast to UITableViewCell lead to crash.

Comment: According to the book, the line should be: `func storyTableViewCellDidTouchComment(cell: StoryTableViewCell, sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("CommentsSegue", sender: cell)
}` sender is set to cell.